# SQL Multiple WHERE IN

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am trying to select the ID from a wp_posts table where I need to do 3 conditions.

1. Is the *ID* matching with the *post_id* from the *wp_postmeta* table where the *meta_key* = 'gtp_analytics_client_id' and the *meta_value* is not empty.
2. Is the *ID* matching with the *post_id* from the *wp_postmeta* table where the *meta_key* = 'gtp_conversion_uploaded' and the *meta_value* is not equal to 1.
3. Is the *ID* matching with the *post_id* from the *wp_postmeta* table where the *meta_key* = 'gtp_lead_revenue' and the *meta_value* is not empty.

I am a beginner with SQL. This is what I have now, but I cannot use multiple IN's. So I think I need to do it another way.

```
SELECT ID 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT post_id 
             FROM wp_postmeta 
             WHERE meta_key = 'gtp_analytics_client_id' AND meta_value != '') 
AND IN (SELECT post_id 
        FROM wp_postmeta 
        WHERE meta_key = 'gtp_conversion_uploaded' AND meta_value != 1)
AND IN (SELECT post_id 
        FROM wp_postmeta 
        WHERE meta_key = 'gtp_revenue' AND meta_value != '')
```

I get the following error:

> *You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN (SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'gtp_conversion_uploaded' A' at line 4*

Comment: Does the above code give you any errors?

Comment: @Matt Yes it does. I have added the error to my question.

Comment: try my answer, should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `and` is not part of the `in` operator, it is three separate `in` operators, so you need the first operand (`ID`) for all of them:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE ID IN ( ... ) 
AND ID IN ( ... )
AND ID IN ( ... )
```

You could also write that as three joins:

```
SELECT
  p.ID
FROM
  wp_posts p
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta m1 ON m1.post_id = p.ID AND m1.meta_key = 'gtp_analytics_client_id' AND m1.meta_value != ''
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta m2 ON m2.post_id = p.ID AND m2.meta_key = 'gtp_conversion_uploaded' AND m2.meta_value != 1
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta m3 ON m3.post_id = p.ID AND m3.meta_key = 'gtp_revenue' AND m3.meta_value != ''
```

Comment: Your answer is in my opinion the best one. Could you explain what you are doing in the JOIN example?

Comment: @Robbert: An inner join has the same effect of limiting the result as a `where id in (...)`.

Answer (score 3):

**When it can be either of the 3 cases**

```
SELECT ID 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT post_id 
             FROM wp_postmeta 
             WHERE (meta_key = 'gtp_analytics_client_id' AND meta_value != '')
             OR (meta_key = 'gtp_conversion_uploaded' AND meta_value != 1)
             OR (meta_key = 'gtp_revenue' AND meta_value != '')
            )
```

Comment: But in this case not all the 3 conditions are true, right?

Comment: Excuse me, no syntax error. My fault. But the checking of meta_key's is still not how I mean it.

Comment: no problem, just delete the comment to avoid future confusion. Regarding the meta key, post a cross section of the output from my code, and then post a sample output of what it SHOULD show in your question and we can go from there.

Comment: the subquery of the 2nd query will never return anything because `meta_key` can't be different values at the same time

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT p.ID 
FROM wp_posts p
JOIN wp_postmeta m on p.id = m.post_id
group by p.id
having sum(m.meta_key = 'gtp_analytics_client_id' AND m.meta_value != '') > 0
and sum(m.meta_key = 'gtp_conversion_uploaded' AND m.meta_value != 1) > 0
and sum(m.meta_key = 'gtp_revenue' AND m.meta_value != '') > 0
```